# Backup Multiple Collections in MongoDB with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to backup multiple collections using javascript but it does not seem to work. I have tried adding and removing and placed semi-colons in different places but still, it would not work.

Here is my code that I am trying to achieve.

```
 var colls = ["inventory","inventoryA","inventoryC"];

 for(var i = 0; i < colls.length; i++)
  {
   mongodump --db Demo --collection colls.values();
 }
```

I tried executing the javascript file by going to mongodump directory:

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongo multipllecollection.js
MongoDB shell version v4.0.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 4.0.1
2020-04-16T13:11:45.484+0800 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @multipllecollection.js:5:12
failed to load: multipllecollection.js

Where did I go wrong? Thanks

Comment: According to me, writing a shell script and running a cron will be a good idea rather than running it in javascript.

Comment: this is not a valid js statement `mongodump --db Demo --collection colls.values();`

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use excludeCollection() or excludeCollectionsWithPrefix but is tedious when having so many collections.